# Can I restore an app I removed from list on my Droid Razr?

Tags: applications, motorola-droid-razr

I just got a Motorola Droid Razr M. I've deleted some apps by accidentally tapping <kbd>Remove From List</kbd> rather than just swiping them off the screen. Is there a way to get these back?

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't actually deleted the app, as that would have to be done via the Play Store or Settings menu. <kbd>Remove From List</kbd> should only remove an app from the multi-tasking list, or at most close the background process.

Check the list of apps in your task launcher and you should still find it available.

Answer (score 1):

If they are the apps came originally with your device (and are not available for download in the Play Store), you can back up your phone and go for a factory reset. Restore everything afterwards. This option would be fine since your device is still new.

If the apps are available for download at Google Play Store, simply go there and install them. This option will save some trouble for you.